# Why my Dockerfile build-arg is not working as ENV

Tags: dockerfile

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG VER=INVALID
FROM python:${VER}
ENV VERSION ${VER}
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo VERSION = $VERSION"]
```

To build it I use:

```
sudo docker build --tag teste --build-arg VER=3 .
```

And when I run it, I'm getting:

```
$ sudo docker run teste
VERSION =
```

If I run it using the `export` command, I'm getting the `VERSION` ENV empty:

```
$ sudo docker run teste /bin/bash -c export
...[other ENVs]...
declare -x PYTHON_VERSION="3.9.7"
declare -x VERSION=""
```

But the `VER` build-arg seems to working for the image base version (`FROM python:${VER}`).

Why? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the docker DOC:

> An ARG declared before a FROM is outside of a build stage, so it can’t be used in any instruction after a FROM. To use the default value of an ARG declared before the first FROM use an ARG instruction without a value inside of a build stage:

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

So, I solved **redeclaring** the ARG after the `FROM`, like this:

```
ARG VER=INVALID
FROM python:${VER}
ARG VER
ENV VERSION ${VER}
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo VERSION = $VERSION"]
```